# MAUI support for PAX terminal e800

Tags: android, maui

I am new to Android and a little confused. I have a PAX e800 terminal the installed (OS) PayDroid Powered by Android 6.0 + (Q20) Prolin with a Cortex A17 + (Q20) Cortex A7 processor.

I have no problems building and producing a Signed APK. However when I try to install it on the terminal I get an error **INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS**. I understand this to mean that my APK does not support the Device processor.

I have tried to add this to the project file

android-arm;android-arm64;android-x86;android-x64

But its still a problem.

As I said I am new. so dont know if I am even on the right path. I have deployed a App developed in Andriod Studio to the terminal but would much prefer if I could develop in MAUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the project file

android-arm;android-arm64;android-x86;android-x64

and this

True

It will produce hardware specific APKs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).